# Google text to speech not working C# Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, google-text-to-speech

I am using google text-speech to convert my text to speech on a button click, it works fine when I set manually text like

```
var textview = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
            textview.Text = "anuthing to speak";
```

but when i set textview text from my following function it says nothing

```
public string CovertChapterToText(EpubChapter chapter)
        {
            HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(chapter.HtmlContent);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()"))
            {
                sb.AppendLine(node.InnerText.Trim());
            }
            string chapterText = sb.ToString();
            return chapterText;
        }
```

like

```
    textview.Text = CovertChapterToText(chapterToBeShown);
```

button click event

```
 btnSpeak.Click += delegate {

                    // if there is nothing to say, don't say it
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textview.Text))
                        textToSpeech.Speak(textview.Text, QueueMode.Flush, null);

            };
```

Comment: have a look at this if you already not [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/text-to-speech/).

Comment: @ADM same issue, no errors no warnings but it does not read the text of chapter :/

Comment: What is the nuget package you are using that contains `EpubChapter`? And would you mind sharing a basic demo to reproduce this problem? That's really appreciated!

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EpubReader.Cross/ 
(using this nuget package)
https://github.com/virux99/Ebook-reader-android-xamarin
(ink of my project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why. But google tts donot reads text that was out of screen. When i remove some characters from end it started to work like charm